# Accessing SVN VCN# for ECR database

Tags: python, tortoisesvn

Working on automating an Access database. Getting stuck trying to access the current version control number from SVC to place it in an Access report (which will be sent to signal ECR completion to the requestor). The current project is in python, not my strongest language.

Not sure if this is the best way to go about it, but it is what I am working with. So, how do I query for the current version control number? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Currently added a line to the database to manually enter the SVN number as a temp workaround until I figure out how to automate this. Did not share code because I am using multiple programs currently to automate this. Basically, a distributed CRUD that writes to files (during the engineering meets we modify the files) and then uses the modified files to update the database. Hopefully, as it evolves so will my skill with python.